# How can i calculate a progress between 2 API checks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on the website for a webradio and have the following problem:

I have a webplayer on the site which shows a progress bar for the current song. Via an API I get the length of the song, the remaining seconds until the song ends and how far the song has progressed at the moment.

Currently, I request this data every 5 seconds, which draws a lot of data volume on mobile devices and also makes the progress bar jump.

Is it possible to calculate the progress of the song in this time between two requests to the API and thus increase the interval between two requests and make the progress bar smoother?

I'm grateful for every response and help!

My API-Response:

```
current: {
  live: false,
  artist: "DVBBS",
  title: "TSUNAMI",
  albumArt: "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/6d/1c/54/6d1c5489-73ad-ba58-3f7d-3e1db8921062/source/500x500bb.jpg",
time: {
  duration: 237,
  elapsed: 140,
  remaining: 97
}
```

My current code:

```
let elapsed = value.current.time.elapsed;
let duration = value.current.time.duration;

let percent = Math.ceil(elapsed / (duration / 1000) / 10);

$(c).find('.progress').css({
    'width': percent + '%'
});
```

Comment: IMHO, mobile devices calling an API every 5 secs is acceptable, if the API response size is just a few bytes. If the API is returning a huge response, then the API is the one that needs attention.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna increase elapsed by one second everytime regardless you get a response each second or five seconds like this

```js
let keepProgress = () => {
  setInterval(function() {
    elapsed += second; //considering elapsed is expressed in ms 
    percent = Math.ceil(elapsed / (duration / 1000) / 10); //recalculate the song percentage
    $(c).find('.progress').css({
      'width': percent + '%'
    });
  },second);
}
```

And you might need a function to determine each 5 seconds if the elapsed estimated time is at par with the response elapsed value like this

```js
let fixedUpdate = (elapsed) => {
  if (elapsed !== response.elapsed) {
    percent = Math.ceil(elapsed / (duration / 1000) / 10); //recalculate using the elapsed value response 
    $(c).find('.progress').css({
      'width': percent + '%'
    });
  }
}
```

That way you keep an estimated value each second, a responsive percentage bar, and a way to adjust the progress